# which is better... in-memory search or database access?

Tags: c#, caching, search, web

We're working on an online system right now, and I'm confused about when to use in-memory search and when to use database search. Can someone please help me figure out the factors to be considered when it comes to searching records?

Answer (score 4):

One factor is that if you need to go through the same results over and over, be sure to cache them in memory.  This becomes an issue when you're using linq-to-sql or Entity Framework—ORMs that support deferred execution.

So if you have an `IQueryable<SomeType>` that you need to go through multiple times, make sure you materialize it with a `ToList()` before firing up multiple foreach loops.

Comment: 1+ very good point many of us forget to actually execute the IQueryable or IEnumerable .ToList() or .SingleOrDefault() or FirstOrDefault() only when you need the result. This can greatly effect performance by deplaying too late or being too early.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the number of records. If the number of records is small then it's better to keep that in memory, i.e cache the records. Also, if the records get queried frequently then go for the memory option.

But if the record number or record size is too large than it's better to go for the database search option.

Basically it depends on how much memory you have on your server...

Comment: Not quite; there are other issues. If you cache, you add complexity. You need to come up w/ a cache invalidation and cache refresh strategy. Depending on how you do it, it could end up being a lot of code.

Comment: @Esteban Araya  - who is talking about the code part...read the question its about putting record in memory or access from database thats it...

Comment: @PranayRana the question asks for factors to consider. Code complexity (and therefore maintenance costs) is an important factor.

Comment: @Pranay: in my view its all about optimization, we should consider every point of view, it may be code as well as searching techniques.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the situation, though I generally prefer in memory search when possible.

However depends on the context, for example if records can get updated between one search and another , and you need the most updated record at the time of the search, obviously you need database search.

If the size of the recordset (data table) that you need to store in memory is huge,  maybe is better another search directly on the database.

However keep present that if you can and if performance are important loading data into a datatable and searching, filtering with LINQ for example can increase performance of the search itself.

Another thing to keep in mind is performance of database server and performance of application server : if the database server if fast enough on the search query, maybe you don't need to caching in memory on the application and so you can avoid one step. Keep in mind that caching for in memory search move computational request from database to the application server...

An absolute response is not possible for your question, it is relative on your context ...

Comment: Ahhh thanks for your answer, at least I had an idea that caching depends on the situation.

Comment: In short : when the record to be retrieved is not too large, it's better to use cache... but when the record(s) to be retrieved is/are frequently accessed, too large be put into a datatable, and always having updates, then, it's better to do database search.. right??

Comment: Yes, I suggest you to do some test with the database search if performance are good you can , if instead performance are a prerogative you should consider the in memory approach... However bear in mind my considerations of the answer .